# Current test status in xUnit.net

Tags: unit-testing, xunit.net

How can I get status of currently executed test? I'd like to know in Dispose() method if current test failed or not. This should be something similar to mstest's 
TestContext.CurrentTestOutcome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've asked the same question on xunit site and I can share the answer here too. 
Basicaly according to https://github.com/xunit/xunit/issues/398 there is no way to know test status inside the test. Also according to https://github.com/xunit/xunit/issues/416 there is no such thing as TestContext in xunit.

Answer (score 3):

While it is correct that xUnit doesn't have an API that supports showing if the current test has failed, Simon Cropp has made a Nuget package called XunitContext which supports that you can ask the test if it has failed:

https://github.com/SimonCropp/XunitContext#test-failure

https://www.nuget.org/packages/XunitContext/

*When a test fails it is expressed as an exception. The exception can be viewed by enabling exception capture, and then accessing Context.TestException. The TestException will be null if the test has passed.*

I use it like this with MS Playwright, to ensure I only save a trace when the test fails as they can take up a lot of disk space:

```
string? tracePath = GetTracePath(testName);   
                
// Stop tracing and save data into a zip archive.
await context.Tracing.StopAsync(new TracingStopOptions
{
    Path = tracePath
});


private static string? GetTracePath(string? testName)
{
    // Only save trace if the test failed, since it can take up a lot of space in CI. 
    // TestException will be null if there was a failure in the test, in this case we set the tracePath to null, which Playwright interprets as "do not write the trace file".
    // See https://github.com/SimonCropp/XunitContext#test-failure and https://github.com/microsoft/playwright-dotnet/issues/1964
    return XunitContext.Context.TestException == null ? null : Path.Combine("Traces", "Trace_" + testName + ".zip");
}
```

For this to work you need to set up the following as well:

```
public class GlobalSetup
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Allows using Context.TestException from XUnitContext. See https://github.com/SimonCropp/XunitContext#test-failure
    /// </summary>
    [ModuleInitializer]
    public static void Setup() => XunitContext.EnableExceptionCapture();
}
```

Have your Test class inherit from XunitContextBase

```
public abstract class PlaywrightTestBase : XunitContextBase, IClassFixture<DatabaseFixture>, IAsyncLifetime
```

and call the base ctor with testOutputHelper and sourcefile like this:

```
protected PlaywrightTestBase(PlaywrightFixture playwrightFixture, DatabaseFixture databaseFixture, ITestOutputHelper testOutputHelper, [CallerFilePath] string sourceFile = "") 
        : base(testOutputHelper, sourceFile)
```

You can access all of this in the Dispose method as well:

```
public override void Dispose()
{
    var theExceptionThrownByTest = Context.TestException;
    var testDisplayName = Context.Test.DisplayName;
    var testCase = Context.Test.TestCase;
    base.Dispose();
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, for this exact use case! Thanks!