XUnit - TestCaseOrderer - Break if fail
I use the PriorityOrderer describe here :
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/testing/order-unit-tests?pivots=xunit
It works fine, but i would like to break if a test fail.
Something which would look like :
        foreach (TTestCase testCase in
            sortedMethods.Keys.SelectMany(
                priority => sortedMethods[priority].OrderBy(
                    testCase => testCase.TestMethod.Method.Name)))
        {
            yield return testCase;
            if (HasFailed(testCase))
            {
                yield break;
            }
        }

But i can not find how to make my hasFailed function

Have you tried enabling xUnit's stopOnFail setting?

Set this to true to stop running further tests once a test has failed.

xunit.runner.json
{
    "$schema": "https://xunit.net/schema/current/xunit.runner.schema.json",
    "stopOnFail": true
}

Your .csproj
<ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="xunit.runner.json" CopyToOutputDirectory="PreserveNewest" />
</ItemGroup>


That seems close to what i would like, but what i want is to prevent the run only of the tests with the same PriorityOrderer.

You might be able to get the test failure status from the TestContext (built-in with xUnit 3, or with the XunitContext package with xUnit 2). See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/75656473/979493.
